# how to have title in double quotes in html or asp tag

Tags: asp.net, html

For a `title` tag, I have given as title="I name accept " and it shows as `I name accept`.

But I want to give title as `I "name" accept`. How to put double quotes for a title tag in double quotes.

thanking you,

michaeld

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `&quot;` instead.

```
Title="I &quot;name&quot; accept"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
title="I &quot;name&quot; accept"
```

You could do it like this too:

```
title='I "name" accept'
```

But I would go with the first one :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the HTML code of the ASCII character. Here's the table of [HTML Codes - Characters and symbols](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm)

Double quotes should be: &quot;

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
Title = 'I "name" accept'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using ASCII characters, the character for " is "

[HTML ASCII Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_ascii.asp)